# Static timed loop in objective-c cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, loops, cocos2d-iphone

Looking for some ideas on how to implement this, don't necessarily need the exact code.

Let's say I have a game where the player's hit points are displayed in a label, say 100HP. When he takes damage, say 30 damage, I want that label to count down from 99, 98 , 97 ... 70. It should take 2 seconds to perform the countdown whether you take 30 damage or 3000 damage.

I'm wondering what's the most efficient way to get this loop to count down "smoothly" over 2 seconds no matter what the damage taken is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably extend a CCLabelSomething to do that, embedding the desired behaviour. Suggest a fixed width font, otherwise nothing smooth will happen (visually). Figure out what is 'smooth for you', ie how many updates in the 2 second period. in the assumed 'setScore' public method, start a scheduled update cycle with appropriate delay. In the schedule callback, change the text of the label.

say 20 updates, ie 10 per seconds. Schedule with .1f delay between intervals. Upon setScore, compute the 'delta' per update (currentScore - newScore)/20. Decrement currentScore down to newScore by this delta. In the schedule callBack, stop your scheduled update if the displayed score is equal to the newScore.